Mounting camera using jmtpfs within a udev rule
I am trying to use jmtpfs to mount my GoPro to transfer files when I plug it into my computer.
I have a script that works outside a udev rule. However, when run inside the udev rule the script fails and disconnects my USB device.
A minimal working example is given here:
script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
jmtpfs /media/GoPro > /tmp/gopro.log 2> /tmp/gopro.err

udev rule
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2672", ATTR{idProduct}=="004b", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash -c /home/matt/Projects/GoProScraping/scripts/grab_go_pro_files.sh"


The output of the file /tmp/gopro.err is:
Device 0 (VID=2672 and PID=004b) is UNKNOWN in libmtp v1.1.19.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted

The output of journalctl -f is:
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2672, idProduct=004b, bcdDevice= 0.01
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: Product: GoPro MAX
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: GoPro
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: C3351325091705
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina sudo[1455]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/jmtpfs /media/GoPro
Sep 29 09:45:31 nina sudo[1455]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Sep 29 09:45:34 nina sudo[1455]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 29 09:45:34 nina kernel: usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 16
Sep 29 09:45:34 nina systemd-udevd[1453]: 1-4: Process '/bin/bash -c /home/matt/Projects/GoProScraping/scripts/grab_go_pro_files.sh' failed with exit code 1.

It looks like I plug the GoPro in, udev picks up that it's connected, then there's a permission error and the error causes the USB to be disconnected and then udev picks it up again.
However, if I try running the command: jmtpfs /media/GoPro as the root user it mounts well and I can access files manually.
I thought udev rules run as root, what am I missing?

You might be trying to follow obsolete advice. Running arbitrary things from udev rules used to be possible, but then a security hole was found, and some restrictions were applied. Now the systemd-udevd service process is usually sandboxed, which limits its direct actions to basically just creating, probing and deleting device nodes. But it can still tell systemd to start other things.
On modern systems, the chapter on the RUN keyword in man udev says:

This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks. Running an event process for a long period of time may block all further events for this or a dependent device.
Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service.
Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not allowed; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished. In order to activate long-running processes from udev rules, provide a service unit and pull it in from a udev device using the SYSTEMD_WANTS device property. See systemd.device(5) for details.

So, first create a service file, e.g. /etc/systemd/system/gopro-jmtpfs.service, with the following contents:
[Unit]
Description=Mount GoPro when plugged in
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=exec
# if your systemd does not have Type=exec, use Type=simple instead
ExecStart=/usr/bin/jmtpfs /media/GoPro

This defines a static unit, which cannot be started manually. It will be triggered by an udev rule later.
And another service for your file-grabbing script, e.g. /etc/systemd/system/gopro-grabfiles.service:
[Unit]
Description=Grab files from a mounted GoPro
After=gopro-jmtpfs.service
ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/media/GoPro

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /home/matt/Projects/GoProScraping/scripts/grab_go_pro_files.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=gopro-jmtpfs.service

After creating the service file, remember to run systemctl daemon-reload to have it take effect.
Then create an udev rule for your GoPro like this:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2672", ATTR{idProduct}=="004b", TAG+="systemd", SYSTEMD_WANTS+="gopro-jmtpfs.service"

Now the gopro-jmtpfs.service should be started automatically when the GoPro is plugged in, and gopro-grabfiles.service should trigger after the first service has started running.
Tagging a udev rule with TAG+="systemd" should cause systemd to become aware of the device in question, resulting in a *.device unit getting automatically created for it. You will be able to use that for further systemd-based automation if you wish.
By default, the name of the device unit will be a long and awkward sys-devices-pci...-usb....device string, but you can add ENV{SYSTEMD_ALIAS}="/sys/subsystem/usb/somename" to your udev rule to get a more manageable device unit name.

Thanks so much for the detailed answer!
This very nearly worked for me, though took some tweaking:


new udev
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2672", ATTR{idProduct}=="004b", RUN+="/bin/systemctl restart gopro-jmtpfs.service"


I uncommented the user_allow_other in vim /etc/fuse.conf


new systemd:


Description=Mount GoPro when plugged in
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=matt
ExecStart=/home/matt/Projects/GoProScraping/scripts/mount_gopro.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


Oh, and I moved the mount point to /home/matt/GoPro as perm issues were giving me trouble.
